# Creating images from .tif file using Imagick in PHP

Tags: php, html, imagick

I'm unable to use Imagick in PHP to create images. I have created a log file to debug the function in use, but I don't get much from it.
I have check the $sourcePath, $destPath, $fileExtension and all are fine.

convert -version:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

// Function used to create Thumnail

```
    function CreateThumnail($sourcePath, $destPath, $fileExtension)
    {
        $maxCoreNum = 4; // set maximum number of cores
        $tempPath = ""; 
        
        if (strtoupper($fileExtension) == "TIF" || strtoupper($fileExtension) == "TIFF") 
        {
            $tempPath = str_replace("thumb.jpg","temp.tif",$destPath);

            //flatten image
            $command = 'gdal_translate -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=LZW" -co "BIGTIFF=YES" -ot Byte -scale "'.$sourcePath.'" "'.$tempPath.'"  2>&1';
            exec($command, $output);
            
            $image = new Imagick($tempPath);
            
            $image->setImageColorspace(255); 
            $image->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
            $image->setCompressionQuality(60); 
            $image->setResourceLimit (6, $maxCoreNum); //Set maximum number of cores to use with ImageMagick
            $image->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
            $image = $image->flattenImages(); // Use this instead.
            
            $image->setImageFormat('jpeg'); 

            $image->resizeImage(300, 0, imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED, 1);  
            $image->writeImage($destPath);
    
            $command = 'rm "'.$tempPath.'"';
            exec($command);     
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If this question is just about the `TIF` part, can we remove the second, final `elseif()` block, since it seems to be dealing with jpgs/gifs, and not TIF?  Also: What is the result?  A file?  How big is it?  Is it corrupted?  Have you opened it in GIMP?  What's the error message?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger No image is created in the $destPath. Just the .tif files is there. There is no error message.

Comment: Are you sure your path is correct and that the load is getting an image?  What is FILTER_UNDEFINED? Use FILTER_LANCZOS.

Comment: If you have a multi-page TIFF, you probably need to read it one page at a time by specifying the page in the read by appending [0] for the first page, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Seven years ago, I pointed out a bug to the PHP.net team](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimage.php#111059), showing that `writeImage()` is broken, and in fact, you need to use and `writeImageFile()`.  I suspect this problem must exist also for `readImage()` vs. `readImageFile()`.

Swap your code, `$image->writeImage($destPath);`, and try this in its place...

```
$image = new Imagick();     
$image_filehandle = fopen($sourcePath, 'a+');
$image->readImageFile($image_filehandle);

$image_filehandle = fopen($destPath, 'w+');
$image->writeImageFile($image_filehandle);
fclose($image_filehandle);
```

This should tell you if `fopen()` fails, in case it's not a problem with Imagick at all, and one with permissions and user/file rights.

I have a working project where I use imagick functions, take a look at the source code for icon-resizing and you'll see that I follow pretty much the procedures I describe above: https://github.com/HoldOffHunger/GreenGluonCMS/blob/master/traits/scripts/SimpleImages.php

I've always been a fan of Imagick and have always felt it to be underappreciated and underused.  Let me know if this answer helps!

Comment: there was nothing indicating that fopen() failed. I checked $tempPath and the .tif file is there. Nevertheless in $destPath, there is no jpeg file. I also made the changes to use FILTER_LANCZOS

Comment: What's the file size?  Does the file change in size at all?  If the file is zero bytes, that might indicate an error, and if the file size didn't change at all, then no conversion obviously happened.

Comment: The input file is 20020405_P2VP_Cotton_Sorghum_30m_dem.tif (11MB) and there is no output file

Comment: I believe the problem is $tempPath = str_replace("thumb.jpg","temp.tif",$destPath);. In $destPath, there is no thumb.jpg

Comment: Hey, Mark, sorry, I think I found something else wrong!  Take a look: `$image = new Imagick($tempPath);` tempPath is not the sourcePath, it's a modification for it, so, it's not opening the right source Path, I suspect?  I've updated my answer to show how I use it to open a file.  To be clear, this is a fully working example and I know it works -- I maintain a GitHub project that uses this code, see the actual code here: https://github.com/HoldOffHunger/GreenGluonCMS/blob/master/traits/scripts/SimpleImages.php

Comment: I checked $image = new Imagick($tempPath); and the path is correct (there is a file with that name), but it is still not working. What else do you suggest to find the bug here?

Comment: I would suggest not using `new Imagick($path)` at all and using `readImageFile()`, like in my answer. =)